# Creating a client-server(TCP protocol)project where the server sends movies to the client. A problem with the audio when the client performs TIMESHIFT

Tags: python, audio, tcp

I am building a client server project using Python using the TCP protocol. In the project I have a server that saves movies and when a client connects to the server, the server streams the movie to the client, both video and audio. In addition, in the project I'm building, the client can perform a TIMESHIFT, that is, change the time from which he wants to watch. The client sends the requests with the help of a GUI where he can type the time from which he wants to start watching the movie. My problem is that when I perform the TIMESHIFT the video changes immediately while for the audio there is a delay of 11 seconds. That is, it takes the server to send the audio segment 11 seconds after the client sends a request for a new time. I tried to change the CHUNK size of both the server and the client but it didn't help. Is there a way to fix this problem?

here is the server code that sends the audio :

```
def HandleAudio(client_socket, start_time):
global pause_audio
global TimeShiftAudio
global TimeShiftVideo
global NewTime
CHUNK = 2048  
#TODO fix the 11 seconds delay
with wave.open(audio_file, 'rb') as wave_file:
    framerate = wave_file.getframerate()
    bytes_per_frame = wave_file.getsampwidth() * wave_file.getnchannels()
    wave_file.setpos(1000)

    while True:
        # if not pause_audio:
            if TimeShiftAudio:  # time shift audio
                start_frame = int(NewTime * framerate)
                wave_file.setpos(start_frame)
                TimeShiftAudio = False
                audio_chunk = b'\x00' * CHUNK
            audio_chunk = wave_file.readframes(CHUNK)
            if not audio_chunk:
                audio_chunk = b'\x00' * CHUNK
            client_socket.sendall(audio_chunk)

client_socket.close()
```

and here the client code that handles the audio :

```
def HnadleAudio(client_socket):
mute_audio = False #! the mute butten ,if True the sound will be muted
global pause_audio
global pause_video
global quit_transmission
global resetAudio
audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = audio.open(format=audio.get_format_from_width(2), channels=2, rate=44100, output=True)
CHUNK = 2048  # Try increasing the buffer size
#TODO fix the11seconds delay

if quit_transmission:
    client_socket.close()
try:
        while True:
            if not pause_audio:
                audio_chunk = client_socket.recv(CHUNK)                
                if not audio_chunk:
                    break
                try:
                    if not mute_audio:
                        stream.write(audio_chunk)
                except IOError as e:
                    # ALSA underrun occurred, handle it gracefully
                    print(f"ALSA underrun occurred: {e}")
                    # Optionally, you can fill the buffer with silence or take other corrective actions
                    stream.write(b'\x00' * CHUNK)
            if quit_transmission:
                break
                client_socket.close()
except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error in HandleAudio: {e}")
finally:
        stream.stop_stream()
        stream.close()
        audio.terminate()
        client_socket.close()
```

I am using threades to send the video and audio at the same time and of course getting the video and the audio .Despite this, I think there is nothing to do with the threades, these is a problem of the TCP protocol itself. Is there any way to fix this stay?